# Running the following query from my PhpMyadmin SQL tab

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm running the following query from my PhpMyadmin SQL tab:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bansach ON bill AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE addbook
    SET Quality = Quality - (
        SELECT QualitySale
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE book_id = addbook.book_id
    )
    FROM addbook
    JOIN inserted ON addbook.book_id = inserted.book_id
END
```

But everytime I'm getting this error msg:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM addbook
>           WHERE addbook.book_id = inserted.book_id
>   END' at line 10

Comment: unlike sql server, mysql uses OLD and NEW as updated tables.

Comment: Use delimiter `delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bansach ON bill AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE addbook
    SET Quality = Quality - (
        SELECT QualitySale
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE book_id = addbook.book_id
    )
    FROM addbook
    JOIN inserted ON addbook.book_id = inserted.book_id
END;
//
delimiter ;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `delimiter`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bansach ON bill AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE addbook
    SET Quality = Quality - (
        SELECT QualitySale
        FROM inserted 
        WHERE book_id = addbook.book_id
    )
    FROM addbook
    JOIN inserted ON addbook.book_id = inserted.book_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you,but I tried use DELIMITER its announce error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    UPDATE addbook
    SET Quality = Quality - (
        SELECT Quality' at line 2

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bansach  BEFORE INSERT ON bill
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE addbook
    SET Quality = Quality - (
        SELECT QualitySale
        FROM bill
        WHERE bill.book_id = addbook.book_id
    )
    FROM addbook, bill
    WHERE addbook.book_id = bill.book_id
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

Comment: I want to create trigger with two table bill and addbook , when I insert QualitySale then Quality = Quality - QualitySale

Comment: I hope first one is got resolved. You need to use `FOLLOWS TRIGGER_NAME`. here is the nice explanation. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/create-multiple-triggers-for-the-same-trigger-event-and-action-time/